# 16.04 Keyring popup

Tags: 16.04

I just recently upgraded my laptop to 16.04. However, the "keyring" dialog keeps popping up. I've had other flavors of Linux before so I'm sorta familiar with it, but in the last 6 years I've never seen it pop up in ubuntu. How do I get rid of it? It seems to pop up randomly. Seriously, it popped up while I was typing this and this is the only thing running on this computer. There's nothing that should have anything to do with passwords.

Comment: Have you enabled login without password?

Comment: Identified that the keyring password was the old password of my system, and was able to unlock with it.

Answer (score 2):

#### For Ubuntu 16.04:

Open "Password and Keys"
In the view make sure "By Keyring" option is checked.
Then in the left side, right click on keyring or default keyring whatever it is... and click on unlock.
It would ask for the password... for me this was the password I set for the first time I installed ubuntu.
Even if you have changed login password later, enter the password used for the first time, it should work...
If it does, right click on keyring again and delete it.
(It would also delete any passwords it might have saved)